# Trying to fill ViewModel from result set and pass to View, but cannot due to its scope

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, scope, viewmodel

I am calling a stored procedure with entity framework from my controller and then receiving the result set back. I am then trying to use the result set to fill my ViewModel and pass it to the view through a controller action. The issue is that I must call the stored procedure from inside an `if` statement, so due the scope I cannot access it to pass it through the controller action.

Here's an example (Inside a controller action):

```
if (dropdown1 == "Name")
                {
                    var Results = entities.Report(SomeInputParameter).ToList();

                    var viewModel = new ReportingViewModel { Reports = Results };
                }
```

`Report` is my stored procedure and `Reports` is the ViewModel object I am trying to fill.

Since it is inside an If statement I cannot access it to pass it to the view like this:

```
return View("ReportGenerator", viewModel);
```

Any help on the best way to access this would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Declare it outside...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot you just declare it outside of the `if`?

```
ReportingViewModel viewModel = null;
if (dropdown1 == "Name")
{
    var Results = entities.Report(SomeInputParameter).ToList();

    viewModel = new ReportingViewModel { Reports = Results };
}

return View("ReportGenerator", viewModel);
```

Just make sure to initialize it appropriately

Comment: Tried this, and it didn't work. But I didnt initialize it to null

Comment: @cfly24, local variables always have to be initialized before they are used, so yeah, assign it some value, like null or `new ReportingViewModel()`